# POSTGRES: problems on functions in workweek

Tags: postgresql

Im newbie on postgres function and im trying to work on a working business hours using a function and getting the following error when i combine the two functions.

I just want a function that will past the 2 date ranged and will return a result in minutes.

**1st function: Get the time in date ranged.

RUN: SELECT f_work('2013-09-13 06:00','2013-09-13 07:00')

Result: 01:00**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_work (
  t_start timestamp,
  t_end timestamp
)
RETURNS interval AS
$body$
SELECT (count(*) - 1) * interval '1 min'
FROM   (
   SELECT $1 + generate_series(0, (extract(epoch FROM $2 - $1)/60)::integer)
             * interval '1 min' AS t
   ) sub
WHERE  extract(ISODOW from t) > 0
AND    t::time >= '06:00'::time
AND    t::time <  '19:00'::time
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
```

**2nd function: Convert time in minutes.

RUN: select to_min('01:00')

Result: 60**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_min(t text)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
    hs INTEGER;
    ms INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM  t::time) * 60) INTO hs; 
    SELECT (EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM t::time)) INTO ms;
    SELECT (hs + ms) INTO ms;
    RETURN ms;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

**Joining the two function i got and error:

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "f_bizwork" line 6 at SQL statement**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_bizwork(t_start timestamp,t_end timestamp)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    hs INTEGER;
    ms INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT (count(*) - 1) * interval '1 min'
FROM   (
   SELECT $1 + generate_series(0, (extract(epoch FROM $2 - $1)/60)::integer)
             * interval '1 min' AS t
   ) sub
WHERE extract(ISODOW from t) >0 
AND    t::time >= '06:00'::time
AND    t::time <  '19:01'::time;

SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM  sub::time) * 60) INTO hs; 
SELECT (EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM sub::time)) INTO ms;
 SELECT (hs + ms) INTO ms;
RETURN ms;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: What's unclear about "* query has no destination for result data*"?

Comment: OK, I've upvoted the question. Sometimes even basic error message looks very cryptic to someone new to the language.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store results of the 1st query somewhere. Otherwise PostgreSQL does not know what to do with query results and reports that "query has no destination".

This will do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_bizwork(t_start timestamp,t_end timestamp)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    hs INTEGER;
    ms INTEGER;
    sub time;
BEGIN
SELECT into sub (count(*) - 1) * interval '1 min'
FROM   (
   sELECT $1 + generate_series(0, (extract(epoch FROM $2 - $1)/60)::integer)
             * interval '1 min' AS t
   ) sub
WHERE extract(ISODOW from t) >0 
AND    t::time >= '06:00'::time
AND    t::time <  '19:01'::time;

SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM  sub::time) * 60) INTO hs; 
SELECT (EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM sub::time)) INTO ms;
 SELECT (hs + ms) INTO ms;
RETURN ms;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select f_bizwork('2013-09-13 06:00','2013-09-13 07:00')
```

The important line is starting with `SELECT into sub`. This will store results of the query into variable `sub`, which is referenced in the second query.